# HorizontalScrollView with a single sliding text

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I'm busy with a horizontal scroll view with a single textview inside it.
I'm having trouble getting to get textview being able to slide from one side to the other without any space left.

If i just add the textview it's not able to slide.

Basically all i want is a Horizontal scrollview with a textview in the center thats able to scroll either left or right but not overscroll (still visible)

> ```
> eg:
>  |     Text     | 
>  |Text          | 
>  |          Text| 
>
> But not 
>  |ext           |
>  |            Te|
> ```

My current layout looks like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp" >

        <Space
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#808080" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#808080" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: oh yeah and if i remove the space views then my textview cannot be scrolled

Comment: I have to admit Im not sure what you are trying to do is the intended purpose of a scrollview. A scrollviews purpose is to allow you to scroll content which is LARGER than the physical screen real-estate into view. Your textview with a single word is NOT larger than the physical space of the screen. You could try setting your textview width to 280, and set the property of centering the text within it.  This way you at least dont have the 2 spaces.  You are still essentially doing the same thing though.

Comment: Think i'm doing this wrong but please any advice would help, basically i want to the text to appear in the middle and then the user can slide it either to one side or the other. Is the Horizontal Scrollview the wrong view to use?

Comment: I actually think that you have it mostly correct.  I think however what you want to do is get the screen resolution at runtime, then with your textview that wraps content, get its runtime resolution, then make space left and space right' width (at runtime) to (ScreenResWidth-TextViewWidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think that you have it mostly correct. I think however what you want to do is get the screen resolution at runtime, then with your textview that wraps content, get its runtime resolution, then make space left and space right' width (at runtime) to (ScreenResWidth-TextViewWidth).

This means that you will want to give the TextView and both Spaces an ID so that you can access them from within your Java Code.

Use:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to center the text in your textview.

Use:

```
textview.getWidth();
```

in your java code to get the post layout width (in pixels) of the textview.

Use:

```
leftOrRightView.layout(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

to set your left and right space' position and size using the top, left, right, and bottom parameters.

Give your Views IDs in your XML file using:

```
android:id="@+id/myText"
android:id="@+id/myLeftSpace"
android:id="@+id/myRightSpace"
```

Comment: Not exactly what i used but it gave me an idea how to fix my app so thanks :)